# Duration Biases in Survival Analysis

Tags: r, regression, survival, bias

I'm doing a simple Kaplan-Meier Survival analysis, but my survival times, especially my median, is longer than it should be, leading me to believe there is a duration bias. I have person-level data, which includes account number, account open date, account closed date and today's date. The data includes information on accounts open and those that have closed since 2014. There are about 500,000 accounts of which 50,000 are closed.

My data is right censored, so if an account is closed then its considered "dead"=1. If an account is open then its considered "censored" and given a 0.  I calculate the month difference between the account's open date and its closed date. If the account isn't closed then I calculate the month difference between the account's open date and today's date.

Many of the accounts that are open are "loyal" meaning they have remained open for a long period of time (>120 months). I would expect, for example, accounts grouped into product type A to have a median equal to 70 months, but my survival function gives me a median of 220 months.

I'm assuming that because the censored accounts (the ones opened) have a long duration it is biasing the results. My question is what is the best way to deal with this?

Comment: 90% of your data is censored, so it's not surprising to me that you have a very long median survival time - at best, you need to wait for 80% of your population to be censored, at which point you'd hit median survival with the remaining 10% censored and 10% closed. Most people don't close their account, so it'll take a long time to find a population where half the people have closed their account, if that ever happens. I don't really understand what the problem is, the data is what it is - what exactly are you trying to fix?